# Importing module and avoid prepending the name

Tags: typescript, commonjs

I use TypeScript together with CommonJS module loader.

I have one file called `Util.ts` and another called `Main.ts`

I export a class in the `Util.ts` file

```
 export class Set {

 }
```

And I import it in my `Main.ts`

```
import * as Util from "./Util";
```

But in my main file I have to write `new Util.Set()` in order to access the `Set` class. Is there a way such that I can avoid prepending the `Util` identifier? It would be nice if I could write `new Set()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import the class directly like this:

```
import {Set} from './Util';
```

If you have more than one value to import from `Util`, you can do this:

```
import {Set, MyOtherClass} from './Util';
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nathan's excellent answer, which I won't repeat here... you can set an alias for one aspect of the import, if you need to give something a different name:

```
import * as Example from './module1'

// Long hand
var person = new Example.Person('Steve');

// Create an alias (doesn't have to be "Person")
import Person = Example.Person;

// Short hand
var person2 = new Person('Peter');
```